# Eclipse: show problem where the (keyboard) cursor is?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Eclipse mark problems with this red underline, if one place the mouse curor above this line then an error description will pop up. -- How can see that same error description for the text cursor?

*The probelm/marker view is not the solution, because they will show all errors, and I need only the "current" error.*

The solution must work without mouse!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can move the text cursor over the error and press <kbd>F2</kbd> which shows the error and offers solutions as well.

Comment: He asked for solution without using mouse

Comment: my requirement was not to use the mouse, but F2 works for the textcursor too

Comment: I can press my F2 key without using the mouse ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try Ctrl+1. It opens quick-fix menu for current problem. You can see problem description and possible quick solutions

Comment: thanks, but crtl+1 shows only the possible solution but not the probelm

Answer (score 2):

When your caret is in the area where the error is, Eclipse shows the error's description in the lower left corner, below where the package explorer is by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the warnings/error through "ctr+." "ctr+," then press f2 to see the problem description and quick fixes also, then choose appropriate quick fixes or else press "ctr+1" to get quick fixes and then select suitable one.